# Can You Mix and Match Between RAID Controller Connected Hard Drives and Hard Drives Connected to Motherboard via Standard SATA Cables?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hardware-raid

Can You Mix and Match Between RAID Controller Connected Hard Drives and Hard Drives Connected to Motherboard via Standard SATA Cables?

i.e.

- 1x Hardware RAID Controller / HBA Card, connecting to 4 hard drives via a Mini-SAS Cable to a backplane
- 1x hard drive connected directly to the motherboard via a SATA cable

The reason for asking is that I'm having trouble getting Ubuntu Server to install and I'm wondering if this somehow related, i.e. do all hard drives need to be run via the Hardware RAID Controller / HBA Card?

My initial thought was that if I can install Ubuntu Server on the hard drive connected directly to the motherboard, then I can figure out how to get the 4x hard drives connected via the PCIe card later. But when I tried this approach I ended up with the error, "unable to install grub in /dev/mapper" during install.

Comment: It almost certainly depends on the specific hardware and how you want to use the system.  But I have several systems with some drives attached to the motherboard, and some attached to a RAID controller.

Comment: `"unable to install grub in /dev/mapper" during install` - This error doesn't really seem like it has anything to do with how you connect your drives.  When you are installing grub you should be installing to the drive, not LVM.  So something like /dev/sda1 perhaps.

Comment: @Zoredache grub2 has no problem with booting from LVM these days, been there, done that. Wouldn't recommend though, was just trying it. The reason it doesn't work is because he's not installing it to an LVM volume but to /dev/mapper, the folder that HOLDS the volumes.